# Run small Metro app on second monitor

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, modern-ui, windows-store-app

in Windows 8 you can stick a Metro app to a side of the monitor so it runs on the side.

The problem is, that you can do that apparently only on the primary monitor. Is there a way to display it on the secondary monitor?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can load the desired application on the main monitor
2. Load any other metro application (Start menu might work)
3. Move mouse to the top-left corner on the second monitor where the app preview of the target application shows
4. Right click and select "Snap Left" or "Snap Right"

You will now have the target application snapped into small mode on the desired monitor, with the rest of the monitor used as desktop space. I like to do this with skype.

Note, you can still only have one "metro" monitor. Once you move a metro app to the second monitor, the start screen will appear on that monitor as well, and any other metro apps you open will appear on that monitor. If you try to move a metro app back to the main monitor, the sidebar application will be moved from the second monitor to which ever monitor you just moved the other metro application to. *This is a big pain that I hope they fix in 8.1*.

Comment: "This is a big pain that I hope they fix in 8.1" - I sure hope so too, but haven't seen any specific multi-mon Start Screen improvements yet being discussed by the media. Guess we'll see once the Preview's out.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, this works only on my first monitor, but not on my second. On the second monitor I only have the option to close it, not to snpa it left or right.